# Where is the addition from the recurrence relation, in the summation?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, divide-and-conquer

On this coursera course, the instructor is showing how to convert from the recurrence relation into the actual summation of the work done. What I don't understand is where is the constant amout of work at each level `O(n^d)` represented in the summation. Shouldn't it be `a(n/b)+O(n^d)`, instead of `aO(n/b)^d`?
[image]

Comment: Can you clearify exactly which part you don't understand?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a(n/b)+O(n^d), instead of aO(n/b)^d?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the definition of `big-O`, as `a`, `b`, and `d` are constant and greater than `1`, both `aO((n/b)^d))` and `O(n^d)` are equivalent.

Comment: But the recurrence reads: `a(n/b)+O(n^d)`. Shouldn't then the total work be represented by `aO(n/b)+O(n^d)`?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães if `d > 1` they are euivalentin case of `O`. both of them are `O(n^d)`.

Comment: I think I'm not explaining my question properly. I'll try again:

The recurrence relation is ADDing O(n^d) to a(n/b). HOW is `O(n^d) + a(n/b)` equivalent to `aO((n/b)^d))`? HOW did it go from ADDing to MULTiplying?

Answer (score 0):

In the master theorem of your picture, at each level, the work is nothing else, but divide the current level `O(n)`problem into `a-th` next level `O(n/b)`problems, and then combine them up.

In `level 0`, we have only one node in thre tree, this `devide and combine`procedure has a `O(n^d)` time complextity(a given knowledge according to your picture, different algorithms have different `devide and combine` time comlextity).

In `level 1`, we have `a-th` node, and each node have a `devide and combine` procedure, of which the time complextity is `O((n/b)^d)`, so the total `devide and combine` work in this level is `aO((n/b)^d)`.

The total time complexity of the whole work, is the sum of `devide and combine` time complexity of each level.  Keep in mind that the whole work is nothing else, but doing the `devide and combine` all the time.

Comment: that formula comes from the master theorem. I thought it was meant to be universal

Comment: It does can represent different situations, like `O(n)`,`O(n^2)`,`O(n^3)`,etc. But it cann't represent `O(lgn)` or `O(nlgn)`. I suspect there are some cases for these time complextity. See the wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms). The universal one should be `f(n)`